# selenium error ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to click on element in chrome driver browser using python and selenium.
when trying to click i get the element not visible exception.
this is html code:

```
 <div class="mid-content"><ul><li><b><span>Private</span><span><!-- react-text: 715 --> (<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 716 -->
3<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 717 -->)
<!-- /react-text --></span></b></li><li><img alt="" src="../img/UserProfile/lock.svg" width="18" height="24"></li><li class="bottom-title">Request to View</li></ul></div>
```

this is how click by xpath:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="App-content"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/a/div/ul')
```

its not working.
but if i click in chrome driver browser manually first and then run this line of code it's everything working fine. What's the trick?please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to make focus on that webelement first

Comment: There are multiple elements within the html you have shared, which element are you trying to locate?

Comment: When you post HTML and/or code please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE to properly format everything. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find different examples below how you can locate **ul** element.

Get **ul** element by css selector:

```
browser.find_element_css_selector('#App-content .mid-content ul')
```

Get **ul** element that contains "Private" and "3" texts:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="App-content"]//ul[contains(.,"Private") and contains(.,"3")]')
```

Get **ul** element that contains **li** with "Request to View" text and has child **img** tag:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="App-content"]//ul[./li[.="Request to View"] and .//img]')
```